# does "crudely" here means that it was written unskillfully or not?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

does "crudely" here means that it was written "unskillfully" or not?

> There is one factor which has been scarcely touched upon in this
>   examination. It is the character and career of Mrs. Fish, afterwards
>   Mrs. Underhill, who as Leah, the elder sister, plays so prominent a
>   part in the matter. We know her chiefly by her book, " The Missing
>   Link in Modern Spiritualism" (Knox & Co., New York, 1885). This book
>   was written by a friend, but the facts and documents were provided by
>   Mrs. Underhill, who checked the whole narrative. It is simply and even
>   **crudely** put together, and the Spiritualist is bound to conclude that
>   the entities with whom the Fox circle were at first in contact were
>   not always of the highest order. Perhaps on another plane, as on this,
>   it is the plebeians and the lowly who carry out spiritual pioneer work
>   in their own rough way and open the path for other and more refined
>   agencies.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Merriam Webster: crude: marked by the primitive, gross, or elemental or **by uncultivated simplicity or vulgarity**

Answer (score 1):

In context, it does not **necessarily** mean that the book was written poorly. What it **certainly** means is that the substance written about is not "refined," meaning neither sufficiently genteel nor sufficiently intellectual. In addition, it may, and probably does, mean that the book itself is not well written, but that cannot be determined definitively by this quotation.